# highstock single line chart?

Tags: dynamically-generated, highcharts, linechart

I'm trying single line chart in highstock charts i.e. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/  if u seen that graph right side buttom zooming option is there, for that perticular zooming start date and end date showing on right side top i.e. from date and to date. but in code they didn't mention anything.where we have to find that code?

samething for dynamically updated chart also having a zooming option but for this graph there is no from date and to date i.e. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update.
i want from date and to date for this dynamically updated chart. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable this inputs by setting inputEnabled parameter as true

```
inputEnabled: true
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputEnabled